# React - How to fix very inconsistent disabled button countdown (i.e., several whole seconds)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using `setTimeout()` (I even tried [driftless](https://github.com/dbkaplun/driftless) too) to change buttons from `disabled = true` to `disabled = false` 3 seconds after appearing on the DOM (`onLoad=`). The buttons appear in sequence, after the previous button has been clicked.

The problem is, the `setTimeout()` goes absolutely haywire: Each button's `disabled = true` duration is seemingly sporadic (at least on Windows Chrome on 2 different PC's). Sometimes the button seemingly waits the full 3 seconds to enable, sometimes it enables instantaneously, and everything in-between.

What is causing this inconsistency, and how can I get *each* button to enable *exactly* 3 seconds (well, within a couple hundred milliseconds...not a big deal) after appearing?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/wad11656/pen/GRWrQRX)

**Javascript**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { is_button_disabled: true, show_button_1: true, show_button_2: false, show_button_3: false, show_button_4: false };
  }
  handleDisableButton = (event) => {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ is_button_disabled: false }), 3000);
  }
  handleShowButton = (buttonId) => {
    if (buttonId === 'button_1'){
      this.setState({ is_button_disabled: true})
      this.setState({ show_button_1: false, show_button_2: true})
    }
    if (buttonId === 'button_2'){
      this.setState({ is_button_disabled: true})
      this.setState({ show_button_2: false, show_button_3: true})
    }
    if (buttonId === 'button_3'){
      this.setState({ is_button_disabled: true})
      this.setState({ show_button_3: false, show_button_4: true})
    }
    if (buttonId === 'button_4'){
      this.setState({ is_button_disabled: true})
      this.setState({ show_button_4: false, show_button_1: true})
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { show_button_1, show_button_2, show_button_3, show_button_4 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div butttons>
        {show_button_1 &&
          <button onLoad={this.handleDisableButton()} onClick={() => this.handleShowButton('button_1')} disabled={this.state.is_button_disabled}>Button1</button>
        }
        {show_button_2 &&
          <button onLoad={this.handleDisableButton()} onClick={() => this.handleShowButton('button_2')} disabled={this.state.is_button_disabled}>Button2</button>
        }
        {show_button_3 &&
          <button onLoad={this.handleDisableButton()} onClick={() => this.handleShowButton('button_3')} disabled={this.state.is_button_disabled}>Button3</button>
        }
        {show_button_4 &&
          <button onLoad={this.handleDisableButton()} onClick={() => this.handleShowButton('button_4')} disabled={this.state.is_button_disabled}>Button4</button>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix this first.

```
<button id="myButton" onLoad={this.handleDisableButton} onClick={() => this.handleShowButton('button_1')} disabled={this.state.is_button_disabled}>Button1</button>
```

which means

```
this.handleDisableButton()
```

to

```
this.handleDisableButton
```

And `clearTimeout` to prevent memory leak

I have fixed your sandboxcode:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandler);
      this.setState({ is_button_disabled: false });
    }, 3000);
  }
  handleShowButton = (buttonId) => {
    let newState = {};
    if (buttonId === "button_1") {
      newState = {
        is_button_disabled: true,
        show_button_1: false,
        show_button_2: true
      };
    }
    if (buttonId === "button_2") {
      newState = {
        is_button_disabled: true,
        show_button_2: false,
        show_button_3: true
      };
    }
    if (buttonId === "button_3") {
      newState = {
        is_button_disabled: true,
        show_button_3: false,
        show_button_4: true
      };
    }
    if (buttonId === "button_4") {
      newState = {
        is_button_disabled: true,
        show_button_4: false,
        show_button_1: true
      };
    }
    this.setState(newState, () => {
      this.timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandler);
        this.setState({ is_button_disabled: false });
      }, 3000);
    });
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandler);
  }
```

Comment: The `clearTimeout()` was key: The memory leaks from not clearing it were causing the problem. I started by making the timeout a global variable, assigning that global variable when needed, then putting a bunch of `clearTimeout()`s everywhere where needed. However, I implemented your code afterwards. I'll need to read a bit more into `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()`. Like another person said, `<button>` apparently doesn't have an `onLoad` parameter, so simply changing `onLoad=handleDisableButton()` to `onLoad=handleDisableButton()` doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. It's important to understand when to clearTimeout inside the component lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

While using setState, can you try
`this.setState({ ...this.state, is_button_disabled: true}) this.setState({ ...this.state, show_button_4: false, show_button_1: true})`

Comment: I added `...this.state` to each `setState()` parameter list under `handleShowButton()`, but now the buttons all enable instantaneously.

Comment: I think your `onLoad` should be something like `onLoad={this.handleDisableButton}` , don't execute the function !

Comment: Changing `onLoad={this.handleDisableButton()}` to `onLoad={this.handleDisableButton}` makes it so the button never enables

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onLoad` event for buttons, which is why the method is never getting called if you pass it in by reference and only gets called when invoked directly.

You should call `handleDisableButton()` as a callback to `setState()` in your `onClick` method, ie:

```
if (buttonId === "button_1") {
  this.setState({
    is_button_disabled: true,
    show_button_1: false,
    show_button_2: true
  }, () => {
    handleDisableButton();
  );
}
```

This ensures that the timeout will start only once the state has been updated, and the timeout callback should consistently be called after 3 seconds.